# Gatsby navigate() with query parameters

Tags: gatsby, query-string, reach-router

I am at an odd stuck point. I am trying to navigate programatically using *navigate()* from gatsby (I tried @reach/router as well). But whenever I add query parameters to the url like so:

```js
const id = "001"
const title = "information"
navigate(`/subpage?id=${id}&title=${title}`);
```

I navigate to the 404 page ,despite the correct url showing in the address bar, including the parameters. Once I reload the page, everything works.

I found some answers but for some reason, none of them worked for me. Is there anything  else you can think of that I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Does it have the same behavior in `gatsby develop` as well as `gatsby build`?

Comment: @FerranBuireu I am not quite sure how to run the output of Gatsby build locally. If you can give me a pointer I'll try it out.

Comment: Just run `gatsby build` and once done `gatsby serve`. By default you'll see your built site at `localhost:9000/`

Comment: @FerranBuireu Thanks for the heads up. I just tried it and it seems as if the error only appears during development with ```gatbsy develop```, not after running the build output with ```gatsby serve```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Thanks for the heads up. I just tried it and it seems as if the error
> only appears during development with gatbsy develop, not after running
> the build output with gatsby serve.

That's what I thought. This happens because Gatsby does redirects in production on navigation but it doesn't check if it should redirect during the initial render like the scenario you described in development.

Run:

```
gatsby build && gatsby serve
```

To build your site and see the expected result. The navigation should be fine.

Comment: So is there a workaround to make it work during development, or is there another way to implement this that more closely resembles Gatsby best practices?

Comment: It's Gatsby's behavior so as far as I know, there's nothing you can do rather than building your site locally  and testing it.

Comment: `gatsby build...` command, missed `s`